# CSS: multi-column dropdown

Tags: html, css, menu, drop-down-menu

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4z2Vx/

I'm trying to create a multi-column dropdown/menu widget.

[image]

The image on the left is in my web site, the left inside jsFiddle. Apart from the obvious colour + font, I'm not sure why jsFiddle is tampering with the alignment. This is not the issue, the issue is the first column is being hidden under the second... I've tried for hours but can't get them to display side by side.

Comment: What do you mean by side by side? you want all link side by side? like one big row?

Comment: The alignment is fine in Opera, FYI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `float` doesn't work on absolutely positioned elements, you can either restructure your html so as you have an absolutely positioned parent above `.first` and `.second` (as griswoldo's answer); or set a width for the dropdowns and then position them:

```
.dropdown li ul { 
    display: none; 
    border:black 1px solid;  
    position:absolute;
    background-color:white; 
    width: 150px;  /*set the width*/  
} 


.second {
    left: 150px; /*set the position*/
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tYeDk/

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the

```
position: absolute;
```

in the .dropdown li ul rule. If you remove that and then move the "collections" link out of a ul, then you can see both menus side-by-side (and underneath "collections"). Also, you should set float to left for both .first and .second if you want them directly next to each other.

Check out this quick mod I did to your fiddle (not perfect, but I figure you can take it from here): http://jsfiddle.net/4z2Vx/29/

Answer (score 0):

Okay I have gone through your code and understood that you need kind of megamenu. In your code... You have poisoned your sub menu ul absolute and that is the reason it is ignoring to float.

For that you need to make child for yoru absolute positioned

So your HTML wil be

```
<div class="dropdown">
<ul id="menus"><li>Collections
        <ul class="sub">
            <ul>        
            <li><a href="#">ABC/BBC</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Animated</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Children</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Documentary</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Drama</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Cult</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Family</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Fantasy</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Horror</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Lifestyle</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mystery</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Reality</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sciene fiction</a></li>
       </ul>
      </ul>


</li>
</ul>
</div>​
```

and css will be

```
.dropdown
{
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:400;  
    line-height:40px;
    text-indent:15px;
    padding-right:15px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:inline-block;
}

.dropdown:hover
{
    background-color:green;
}

.dropdown li ul.sub { 
    display: none; 
    border:black 1px solid;  
    position:absolute;
    background-color:white;    
} 

.dropdown ul
{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.dropdown a
{
    display:block; 
    padding-right:15px;  
    line-height:30px; 
}

.dropdown a:hover {
    color: rgb(0,0,0);
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.dropdown li:hover
{
    background-color:green;
}

#menus ul.sub ul{
    float:left
}​
```

with this you can add ul as many as you want...